# Search for a pattern in files and log the result into another file

Tags: unix, scripting, hp-ux

I have a file One.lst that has the following content:

```
a
b
c
```

Now,i have to search in :

```
a_man.lst
b_man.lst 
c_man.lst
```

the pattern : `<inc>true</inc>`.

Now,suppose `b_man.xml` has the above pattern.

So, I have to log `b` in another file, say `Two.lst`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example do:

```
while read line
do
    grep -q "<inc>true</inc>" ${line}_man.lst && echo $line >> Two.lst
done < One.lst
```

- The `while read` keeps reading the file names from `One.lst` and stores them in `$line`.
- `grep -q` checks the existence of `<inc>true</inc>` in `${line}_man.lst`. In case of match, it prints the file name (`$line`) into `Two.lst`.